# Statistical signifiance between two related populations

Tags: statistical-significance, mean, proportion

I have the mean of the number of people below the poverty line for census tracts for the entire state of Washington and also for census tracts of selected counties within Washington. The means come from the same sample/population. One mean comes from the average number of impoverished people in a subset of counties from Washington. The other mean comes from the average number of impoverished people the entire state of Washington. Which method do I use to test for the statistical significance between the two means?

A simplified data of my real data is in the following:

All counties in Washington (each observation is the number of impoverished people within each census tract):

303
372
1516
813
1344
476
300
572
471
978
513
303
315
1315

Selected counties in Washington (again, each observation is the number of impoverished people within each census tract):

351
1137
1819
564
1014

Thank you!
Sincerely,
Lois

Comment: Please give more details on your research questions. Between the two what?

Comment: See this link on how to ask a good question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I wanted to see the statistical significance between two means. The means come from the same sample/population-the state of Washington. One mean comes from the average of impoverished people in a subset of counties from Washington. The other mean comes from the average of impoverished people the entire state of Washington.

Comment: @LoisYenaChang: What does "the statistical significance between two means" mean? Do you mean you want to test whether the difference between the mean poverty rate in all of Washington and the mean poverty rate in your selected counties are different?

Comment: (1) How do you average *people*?   (2) Regardless how you do that, it sounds like you have complete census information.  Why do you need a statistical test?

Comment: @Dougal yes-I'd like to see if I can calculate the statistical significance between the poverty rates of selected counties within Washington and all of Washington (calculated by the average of impoverished people across census tracts). Is this possible?

Comment: Can you put a sample of your data? I find it difficult to answer your question without seeing the data.

Comment: @whuber Sorry! I meant average number of people who are impoverished across census tracts within selected counties in Washington as well average number of impoverished people across all census tracts in all of Washington. I'd like to see if the rates differ between the two samples.

Comment: If you have a complete (and accurate) census, then the rates either differ or they do not.  No test is needed.

Comment: I still have difficulties to wrap my head around your question but you can't test whether 2 means are significantly different or not. One way would be to explore regional differences, if you group counties based on let say North, South, East, West and Central, then I guess you could see if there are regional differences.